# Is there an event that triggers when a cell is edited, but the value doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am working on a sales tracker for our store. We log our sales with the sales tracker and I've got a method that I adapted from a question's answer here at Stack Overflow (Unfortunately I don't have a link or user I can attribute it to at the moment!) for editing a cell without having to mentally add amounts shown below.

```
 function onEdit(e) {


  var editRange = { // C5:O13
    top : 5,
    bottom : 13,
    left : 12,
    right : 12
  };

  //Checks if last value was not a number to avoid loop
  if (isNaN(e.value) == true) {
    return;
  }

  if (isNaN(e.oldValue) == true) {
    var newValue = parseInt(e.value);
  } else {
    var newValue = parseInt(e.value) + parseInt(e.oldValue);
  }

  // Exit if we're out of range
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

  var posRow = parseInt(thisRow);
  var posCol = parseInt(thisCol);

  // We're in range
  var ss = e.range.getSheet();
  ss.getRange(posRow, posCol).setValue(newValue);

} ​
```

This allows the person that sells a device (e.g. worth $645) to add to their current amount (e.g. $450) by typing the current sales over the cell. The code takes the old amount, adds it to the new amount, and saves it back into the cell.

The problem arises when the current sale value is the same as the new sale value (e.g. $500 currently sold, and we just sold $500 again). The values haven't changed because the same value gets typed into the cell, and the onEdit() and onChange() functions do not fire. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: May not be possible, But what you can do is to add a button on to the spreadsheet and assign onEdit function to it. After you edit amount value then click on the button. Boom!

Comment: You will have to change the function name to something else other than onEdit. Because on some came onEdit will fire and you will also click on button which make double entry.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simulate an Event with simple action: Copy-Paste cell to double it:

- Go to cell
- Copy it: `Ctrl + C`
- Paste it: `Ctrl + V` this action will trigger the script.

Here's the code:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var editRange = { // L5:L13
    top : 5,
    bottom : 13,
    left : 12,
    right : 12
  };

  var oldValue, newValue; 

  // check if object was changed
  if (e.value == "[object Object]") {
    oldValue = e.range.getValue();
    newValue = oldValue;
  }
  else {
    oldValue = e.oldValue;
    newValue = e.value;
  }


  //Checks if last value was not a number to avoid loop
  if (isNaN(newValue) == true) {
    return;
  }

  if (isNaN(oldValue) == true) {
    var newValue = parseInt(newValue);
  } else {
    var newValue = parseInt(newValue) + parseInt(oldValue);
  }

  // Exit if we're out of range
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

  var posRow = parseInt(thisRow);
  var posCol = parseInt(thisCol);

  // We're in range
  var ss = e.range.getSheet();
  ss.getRange(posRow, posCol).setValue(newValue);

}
```